# Arbitrary instance for non-null UUID

Tags: haskell, uuid, quickcheck

I am having trouble creating `Arbitrary` instance for some record types that have UUID-fields. A smart constructor ensures that the UUID cannot be null. Is there an idiomatic way to modify the UUID `Arbitrary` instance from `Test.QuickCheck.Instances.UUID` such that it does not generate null values - that is, the generator should not produce `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key piece you need is [`suchThat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:suchThat). When your instance would call `arbitrary` to get a UUID, call `` arbitrary `suchThat` (not . Data.UUID.Types.null) `` instead. Also, if your type defines `shrink`, when shrinking the UUID, do `filter (not . Data.UUID.Types.null)` on the list of shrinks.